# Onelogin roles provisioning

Tags: roles, provisioning, onelogin, scim

I am currently creating a SCIM app for Onelogin.
I have a simple SCIM schema who works well, but I want to have a specific role if someone is in a group.

What I am looking for is to add a JSON Object in an array of role.

**Example:**

If User 1 in group A, then roles should be:

```
{
  "userName": "test",
  ...
  "roles":[{"type":"template", "value":"test_1"}]
}
```

If User 2 is not in any groups, the roles should be:

```
{
  "userName": "test",
  ...
  "roles":[]
}
```

Do you know how I can have something like that in onelogin?